# how to scroll uitableview, and section header in the top, visible and scroll to

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

i have `UITableview` with multiple sections with style group, and light custom header view
after scroll, header not stick in the top, and invisible

i need scroll `UITableview` and section header stick in the top view and visible, like phonebook

how to make it's ?

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320,50)];
    UILabel *labelHeader = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 5, 120, 40)];
    labelHeader.text = [[_groups objectAtIndex:section] objectForKey:@"nameExerciseGroup"];
    labelHeader.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [labelHeader setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:20]];

[headerView addSubview:labelHeader];
    return headerView;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 50;
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

UITableViewStyleGrouped = The section headers and footers do not float.

UITableViewStylePlain = Any section headers or footers are displayed as inline separators and float when the table view is scrolled

You just change the  **UITableViewStyle to UITableViewStylePlain**

Then to scroll to particular row and section programatically  you could use this below UITableViewMethod method.

```
//Scroll to First row in 2 section
[yourTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:1]
                     atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
```

[image]
[image]

[Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Solution does not work in case of sections without rows